# Backing up remote Postgres database

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, scripting, postgresql

I have a Windows 2008 Server machine with a postgres database running on it.  I'd like to back it up daily and have it sent to another machine (running Ubuntu or Windows).  What's the best way to set this up?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/backup.html

Comment: @Iain better to link to `/docs/current/static/` so links don't get stale. Otherwise, add a couple of words and post as an answer; a "no research done first" question can be quite reasonably answered with a "here's the manual" answer.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Cheers, didn't know, all I did was google postgres backup. The postgresql docs are though good in that you can just click the relevant release. I couldn't possibly leave a link only answer, I've downvoted and deleted far too many to get away with that.

Comment: I am familiar with those links, and on how to do a backup.  I was looking for how to do a remote backup, or if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: @NinjaCat What do you mean by a "remote backup"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [postgresql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html), backup options include:

- `pg_dump`, which operates entirely over a PostgreSQL connection so it'll back up from anywhere you can connect to the server from. This is the simple and obvious option that you should prefer unless you know you need something else. Use `pg_dumpall --globals-only` followed by a `pg_dump -Fc` of each database you want to back up.
- `pg_basebackup` to take a backup over the streaming replication protocol. With 9.2 and above, the `--xlog-method=stream` option allows you to do the entire backup over streaming replication with no WAL archiving setup required on the origin server.
- WAL archiving with a base backup for point-in-time recovery.
- `pg_start_backup()`, rsync, and `pg_stop_backup()` with WAL archiving set up.

The first two are wholly remote-initiated backup options.

The latter two require that the server "push" WAL archives to a remote host via the configured `archive_command`, but it still gives you remote backup storage.